# How to ssh to a linux box and execute a mysql command that has a string?

Tags: mysql, shell, ssh

Let's use the example:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh me@host "mysql -uuser -ppwd -t -e 'select * from mydb.mytable where id='$1''"
```

Note a problem: a single quote within a single quote of the command itself. I tried escaping it (\') - no luck, says `"Unmatched '"`. Ideas?

Comment: @Jens then it collides with shell quotes. It's a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "select * from mydb.mytable where id='$1';" | ssh me@host mysql -uuser -ppwd -t
```

Comment: Brilliant! Looks like I don't even need `-e` in the end.

Comment: `-e command` is to execute the given command. Here the command is piped to mysql via ssh, making it easier to handle quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Even @ringo has answered on your exact query but I am posting this due to below reasons-

By ssh you have to share target server with source server. Even there is no need to share the target server with source server via ssh, you can just achieve it by mysql remote connectivity as per below command.

```
mysql -h <targetServerIp> -uuser -ppwd -e "select * from mydb.mytable where id='$1';"
```

Note: Make sure this user should have either global permission or from source server on target mysql server.

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same issue with quotes.

Comment: I am not seeing any quotes issue here. If you are getting any issue then share so that can be taken care...